# VectorDrawable - is it available somehow for pre-Lollipop versions of Android?

Tags: android, gradle, vector, android-vectordrawable

### Background

I've noticed that Android now supports some kind of vector drawing, via a class called "[**VectorDrawable**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html)" (and also [**AnimatedVectorDrawable**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html), BTW). I've found about it by looking at what's new on [**Android-Studio**](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/recent/androidstudio0814released).

I wonder if this would be the end of having to put multiple files into multiple folders (`mdpi`, `hdpi`, `xhdpi`, etc). That would be great and might minimize apps sizes on some cases.

### The questions

I'd like to ask a few questions regarding this new class:

1. Is it possible to use it in older Android versions, maybe via a library of even the support library of Google?
2. I'm not familiar with how it works, but can Lollipop handle SVG files? Can it do anything that is achievable on SVG files?
3. Is there any sample/tutorial/video of using it, other than the documentation I've found?

Comment: As far as I can see, VectorDrawable is the **androidification** of SVG files. I'm using **SVG**s for over an year through the use of **3rd party libraries**, though. ([android-svg](https://code.google.com/p/androidsvg/), [svg-android](https://code.google.com/p/svg-android/) and such). There are similarly named ones. Each one differs from the other ones, so, choose accurately depending on your needs.

Comment: I have made online tool for converting SVG into xml resource vector (lollipop only) - http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/ - It was not tested so much still in early alpha. It support simple svg files (as android supports), I have tested It with inkscape - drawed some shapes (rect,circle,spiral...), select all then "Path->Object to path", exported into *.svg and dropped into site, generated xml and works fine.

Comment: @Yuraj Wow, it's so cool ! great work ! And in such short time... Here, take my +1 . :)

Comment: Concerning http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/... It`s a very usefull tool but I`ve got improper result in such case and I don`t know what is wrong... Hmmm, for further release I wish this tool would notise about bad format... If I used pure svg-files with 3-party libs everything is Ok...

Comment: @AlexZezekalo You should write about it on its Github webpage: https://github.com/inloop/svg2android

Comment: I would like to add a modern library for SVGs: [Sharp](https://github.com/Pixplicity/sharp).

Comment: Android Support Library 23.2 now supports VectorDrawables API 7 onwards and AnimatedVectorDrawables API11 onwards. So the Answer to your question is now YES.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### **UPDATE ON March 2016**

By [Android Support Library 23.2.1](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) update, **Support Vector Drawables and Animated Vector Drawables.** (you can also use latestone for the same)

Please update version of a library in gradle file.

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
```

Vector drawables allow you to *replace multiple png assets with a single vector graphic*, defined in XML. **While previously limited to Lollipop and higher devices**, both `VectorDrawable` and `AnimatedVectorDrawable` are now available through two new Support Libraries *support-vector-drawable* and *animated-vector-drawable.* new `app:srcCompat` attribute to reference vector drawables .

Check source on **github** with some [sample examples](https://github.com/liaohuqiu/android-support-23.2-sample).

**Changes for v7 appcompat library:**

Reverted dependency on vector assets so that developers using the appcompat library are not forced to use `VectorDrawable` and its associated build flags.

Comment: About the vectors support, isn't it enough to update the gradle plugin and use "vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true"   inside  "defaultConfig" ?

Comment: yes, for **Gradle Plugin 2.0+** and for **Gradle Plugin 1.5** you need to add **-->** android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     generatedDensities = []  
  }  

  // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
 }

Comment: Also, please show some code here. A link might be dead some day. You will get +1 for this effort :)

Comment: yes, for sure. will post code in shorttime on git and here.

Comment: The `compile` statement above implies that the project uses `RecyclerView` which is not always the case.

Comment: I assume this won't work on widgets and notifications, right?

Comment: Unfortunately VectorDrawables are still not working on Pre-Lollipop device. I'm on Support Library 23.4.0 and have both  'generatedDensities = []'
and 'vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true' called in defaultConfig{}.

Comment: I implemented ‘AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);’ in the Activity with ‘vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true’ on API Level 23.4.0, however VectorDrawables still crashes the app on pre-Lollipop devices.

Hopefully AppCompat will fix this in the next library release. Very much looking forward to saving a ton of time with VectorDrawables.

Comment: The best way is to use VectorDrawableCompat together with appCompat, which most of you should be using already. More details, please see https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.bbzbmzoc8

Comment: Actual info on how to use appcompat vectors - http://stackoverflow.com/q/40678947/7045114

Comment: so kitkat will support vector images now?

Comment: Perhaps anyone can help... I am trying to convert ibb.co/SdZjjTH to xml using autotracer.org and inloop.github.io/svg2android. It works, but when I try to use it in my app, the app crashes. Can you check if it works for you? Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

**Update 2**: They enable it again in Support Library 23.4.0:

> For AppCompat users, we’ve added an opt-in API to re-enable support Vector Drawables from resources (the behavior found in 23.2) via AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true) - keep in mind that this still can cause issues with memory usage and problems updating Configuration instances, hence why it is disabled by default.

Check this [23.4.0 available now](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/B7QhFkWZ6YX)

**Update**: This doesn't work from version 23.3.0
Check [here](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/iTDmFiGrVne) for details.
Proxy drawables don't work. `app:srcCompat` and `setImageResource()` work, however.

---

Vector Drawable support is available from the Support Library of version 23.2 and beyond. However, to properly use those drawables, they must be referenced indirectly.

**First** step would be to bump the `AppCompat` version.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
```

**Second** enable Vector Drawable support.
If using Gradle plugin, 2.0+

```
android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
   }  
}
```

Otherwise

```
android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     generatedDensities = []  
   }  

   aaptOptions {  
     additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
   }  
}
```

**Third**, refer to the linked [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35800335/4803633).

Comment: yes, i saw this. Thank you for the extended info. I assume that for system wide stuff (notifications, widgets,...) this is of course not available...

Comment: Certain that it should work. Its basically referencing drawables from that point on. Have you tried it? The example there sets a vector drawable to a `MenuItem`, which works fine.

Comment: Are you sure it will work even for notifications and widgets? I'm talking about making it work on old Android versions. How could they handle vectors for this? They can't use the support library, no?

Comment: The whole point of using Support Library version is to make things work in the older versions. As documented, it works all the way back to API 7 and Animated vector drawables from API 11.

Comment: Again, this works inside the app, but what if you try using them outside, like on notifications and widgets? I don't think it will work there, because I don't think you can make other apps (launchers) use the support library, let alone the notification bar. Have you tried it?

Comment: Well, this confirms it. They're unsupported. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201958

Comment: Now it makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

You can try this [support library](https://github.com/wnafee/vector-compat). It supports VectorDrawable and AnimatedVectorDrawable introduced in Lollipop with fully backwards compatibility.

Comment: That library is only compatible with API level 14 and above, whereas the Mr Vector library is compatible down to 7+.

Comment: @donturner: I agree with your point, but I don't think dev's are still developing app's for 7 API.

Comment: Maybe not API 7, but definitely API 10 (Gingerbread) as this accounts for 4.1% of the Android market (https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).

Answer (score 8):

To complement some of the answers here: yes, **you can get support for VectorDrawables pre-Lollipop**, at least partial.

How partial? It depends - I've made [this diagram](https://medium.com/@ferrand.d/can-you-and-should-you-use-vector-drawables-a-cheatsheet-32a2e1cc2ecf) to help (valid for Support Library 23.4.0 to - at least - 25.1.0).

[image: VectorDrawable cheatsheet]

Comment: Indeed, but I think that if you allow it to auto-generate the png files, it should be safe

Comment: Explained in precised manner.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, at this point of time VectorDrawable and AnimatedVectorDrawable are not available in support library. But to avail this feature in Pre-Lollipop versions, you can use the unofficial backport called MrVector.

[MrVector is available in Github](https://github.com/telly/MrVector) and it will support android versions 7+.

**From the official Readme**

To add MrVector dependency add the following line to your build.gradle dependencies block.

```
compile 'com.telly:mrvector:0.2.0'
```

To create the drawable from the vector XML,

```
Drawable drawable = MrVector.inflate(getResources(), R.drawable.vector_android);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: MrVector has been deprecated few days ago in favor of the upcoming VectorDrawableCompat which will be part of the support library.

Comment: Ye, i can't wait to pimp up my app with some fat-ass SVG's :D

Comment: Deprecated. Use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30502261/1954675 instead.

Answer (score 3):

Lollipop cannot handle SVG files without third-party libs.

The best solution I found is the [BetterVectorDrawable](https://github.com/a-student/BetterVectorDrawable) lib together with the [SVG to VectorDrawable Converter](https://github.com/a-student/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter).

**BetterVectorDrawable** is the VectorDrawable implementation for Android 4.0+ with configurable fall-back behavior on Android 5.0+.

**SVG to VectorDrawable Converter** is the batch converter of SVG images to Android VectorDrawable XML resource files. [Online version](http://svg2vector.com)

Links point to readmes, which provide enough information on how to use the lib and the converter.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using VectorDrawable, Android Studio will automatically generate according PNG files (based on your XML files) for Pre-Lollipop versions.

Note that those generated PNG files are considered BitmapDrawables instead of VectorDrawables on devices running API below 21 and therefore can't be animated or similar on those devices.

See "backwards compatibility" for further details:
http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2015/09/android-studio-14.html

Comment: Yes, it was published recently. However, it's using PNGs, instead of using the vectors, so if I change the size of the imageView that holds the image, it will be pixelated/blurry .

Comment: @android developer: You are partially right. This behaviour will occur, but this would be the same for VectorDrawables. Each VectorDrawable has a width and height defined within its XML (e.g. vector_drawable.xml). If this width/height is set to 50x50dp but you set the ImageView size to 100x100dp the result will still be blurred even if you're running Android 5.0 (and therefore are using the VectorDrawable instead of a auto-generated BitmapDrawable).
The real benefit of a VectorDrawable over a common Bitmap is that it tackles screen-dpi into account and therefore won't blur even on 4k displays.

Comment: You mean that VectorDrawable doesn't show well when using a size that wasn't set for it? But it's a vectorized content.... Why would it work otherwise?

Comment: Does it generate pngs for Animated Vector Drawables too?

Comment: No it won't create PNGs for that case. If you want to animate vector drawable on devices running Android version prior to Android 5.0 you might want to try VectorDrawableCompat:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.html

Answer (score 2):

There are no VectorDrawables in the support library at this time.

Funkystein is right -- VectorDrawable is similar to SVG, only supporting the features of vector drawing that are in highest demand so that android can focus on performance. pathData, for example has the same format as SVG's "d" string.

Comment: So this will be relevant only when Lollipop gets popular enough, and even then, it doesn't provide a lot of features. :(

Comment: Do you know of any tutorial/sample/video of the new vector APIs ?

Comment: I've found one now: http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/10/first-look-at-animated-vector-drawable.html#comment-form , https://github.com/chiuki/animated-vector-drawable

Answer (score 1):

The great news is that Google released [Android Support Library 23.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) Support Vector Drawables and Animated Vector Drawables!

But thanks go to the people who ported this library before Google!

> This is where the AppCompat libraries are great, they can bring many
>   of the new features of Android back to much earlier versions. With the
>   newly implemented VectorDrawable class, developers can now use vector
>   images all the way back to API 7 (Android 2.1 Eclair). Animated
>   vectors are a bit more limited, going only as far back as API 11
>   (Android 3.0 Honeycomb), but that still encompasses more than 97% of
>   devices in active use today

Guide to use:

Refer **"[age-of-the-vectors](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.vroh57sfv)"** by @chrisbanes

Comment: Nice! can you please share some samples/tutorials about how to use the new support library's vectors API ?

Comment: Sure ! already added that to my weekend to do list ! :)

Comment: Thank you. If it's short, please also write here.