# How to change color of a Drawable?

Tags: android, android-drawable

In the code I am calling `diamond.xml` with this string:

```
private final Drawable diamond = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.diamond);
```

I draw that with this code:

```
diamond.setBounds(0, 0, 10, 10);
diamond.draw(canvas);
```

In some cases, I need to draw that just changing one or both of the `android:fillColor`. Is it possible? I would like to avoid to create N copies of `diamond.xml` with all the combinations of colors.

**diamond.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:height="100dp" android:width="70dp"
    android:viewportHeight="100" android:viewportWidth="100">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF5722"
        android:pathData="M 5,5 95,5 95,95 5,95 z"
        android:strokeAlpha="1"
        android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:strokeLineCap="butt"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round"
        android:strokeWidth="4"/>

    <path
        android:fillColor="#8BC34A"
        android:pathData="m 50,30 l 20,20 -20,20 -20,-20 z"
        android:strokeAlpha="1"
        android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:strokeLineCap="butt"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round"
        android:strokeWidth="4"/>

</vector>
```

Comment: There is an attribute tint, try with it once

Comment: I wonder how would you do that if you have two paths with two different colors

Comment: yeah you are right, but if u are not getting any direction, u can try once, maybe it recolors all the path, i have tried for images with one path, it worked for them

Comment: You can create themes for all the color combinations and set them to the same drawable XML as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126904/change-fillcolor-of-a-vector-in-android-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

dont use android:fillColor to change value. you can use android:tint="YOUR_COLOR"

Comment: thanks, can you kindly write an example? I don't know where I have to apply that.

Answer (score 0):

Create the themes and set colours inside it,

```
<style name="UpdatedScene" parent="DefaultScene">
<item name="diamond_red">#red_color_hex</item>
</style>
```

and then create the drawable with this theme,

```
final ContextThemeWrapper wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(this,R.style.DefaultScene);
final Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.diamond, wrapper.getTheme());
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Default scene would be your default color to the drawable. while changing the color set the different theme.

Comment: thanks but I have not clear it. Should I edit diamond.xml or it is ok in this way? How can I specify if change the color of the first path or of the second?