# Fillcolor1, Fillcolor2 and strokecolor, Can anyone tell me how can I set all three programatically android?

Tags: android

My app support 23 to 33.

Please check this image below:
[image]

All the 3 things I want it to set programatically for my imageview.

Code:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="12dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                app:icon_imageview_changeSize="false" />
```

What is not working.
If I'm trying to set one thing than it overlaps with other, for ex, tint.
Also there are 2 path. In both path fillcolor are there. How can I programatically set fillcolor differently for path1 and path2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change fillColor of a vector in android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126904/change-fillcolor-of-a-vector-in-android-programmatically)