# Android - How to change the colour of a drawable's path?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-drawable

I have a vector like this

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="16dp"
    android:height="16dp"
    android:viewportWidth="16"
    android:viewportHeight="16">
    <path
        android:pathData="M8,8m-8,0a8,8 0,1 1,16 0a8,8 0,1 1,-16 0"
        android:fillColor="#1c1c1c" />
    <path
        android:pathData="m6.7,12 l-3.7,-3.3 1.3,-1.5 2.3,2 4.9,-5.3 1.5,1.3z"
        android:fillColor="#fff" />
</vector>
```

which by default looks like this:
[image]

and I want to change the colour of the circle programatically (basically the fillColor of the first path) and keeping the tick white.

I was trying to change the tint of the drawable (by using `marker.setTint(tintColor)` and `marker.setTintMode(PorterDuff.Mode.XOR)` or any other variation of tintMode) but no matter what I chose or what tintMode combination I tried I was not able to change the colour of the circle.

Either the colour of the tick was changed, or the correct colour was applied but then the shape of the vector (basically the square) was also shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two different versions of the drawable by changing the `fillColor` attribute of the first path and use either one of them based on your condition.

For example, create a `check_primary.xml` with:

```xml
    android:fillColor="@color/primary"
```

and `check_error.xml` with:

```xml
    android:fillColor="@color/error"
```

Then use them in the code as necessary:

```
if (some_condition)
    setDrawable(check_primary)
else
    setDrawable(check_error)
```

Comment: That's a good idea but I got told that i supposed to change a vector's colour instead of adding new XML files to the project. So I wonder is it possible or it is just a waste of time?

Comment: If you only want to switch between two colors, it makes sense to create another drawable. However, if you want more control, check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126904/change-fillcolor-of-a-vector-in-android-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

```
here you can change using android:fillColor:-
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="16dp"
    android:height="16dp"
    android:viewportWidth="16"
    android:viewportHeight="16">
    <path
        android:pathData="M8,8m-8,0a8,8 0,1 1,16 0a8,8 0,1 1,-16 0"
        android:fillColor="#FF0000" /> <!-- Change the fill color here -->
    <path
        android:pathData="m6.7,12 l-3.7,-3.3 1.3,-1.5 2.3,2 4.9,-5.3 1.5,1.3z"
        android:fillColor="#00FF00" /> <!-- Change the fill color here -->
</vector>
```

Comment: I want to change it progrematically

Comment: Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.your_vector_drawable);
drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable).mutate(); // Wrap the drawable to support tinting on older Android versions
DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, Color.RED); // Set the desired color

// Apply the modified drawable to an ImageView or any other view
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

Comment: First, we retrieve the drawable using ContextCompat.getDrawable(). Then, we wrap the drawable using DrawableCompat.wrap() to support tinting on older Android versions. Next, we mutate the drawable to create a new instance that can be modified independently.

Comment: Finally, we set the desired color using DrawableCompat.setTint(). In this example, we set the color to red (Color.RED), but you can replace it with any color value you prefer.

Comment: The problem with this is my tick disappears

Comment: can you provide code of Class file ?