# How to change color of vector drawable path on button click

Tags: android, vector, vector-graphics, android-vectordrawable

With the new android support update, vector drawables get backward compatibility. I have a vector image with various paths. I want the color of the paths to change on click of a button or programmatically based on an input value. Is it possible to access the name parameter of the vector path? And then change the color.

Comment: you can tint the whole vector, but not single path components

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use this to change a path color in your vector drawable

```
VectorChildFinder vector = new VectorChildFinder(this, R.drawable.my_vector, imageView);

VectorDrawableCompat.VFullPath path1 = vector.findPathByName("path1");
path1.setFillColor(Color.RED);
```

Library is here: https://github.com/devsideal/VectorChildFinder

Comment: But no longer in Maven?

Comment: Ahh, I did not have jitpack.io added. It now finds it, cheers!

Comment: Isn't there a way to change the color of something within the VectorDrawable, without a library? Isn't there anything in the support library for this?

Comment: @Deven I couldnot find the way to change path inside group. Any solutions?

Answer (score 61):

The color of the whole vector can be changed using setTint.

You have to set up your ImageView in your layout file as this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tint="@color/my_nice_color"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_my_drawable"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

Then to change the color of your image:

```
DrawableCompat.setTint(myImageView.getDrawable(), ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.another_nice_color));
```

Note: `myImageView.getDrawable()` gives nullpointerexception if the vector drawable is set to the imageView as background.

Comment: This sets tint to the whole drawable but not a specific path of the vector drawable.

Comment: `android:tint` must be set after setting `android:src`

Comment: What about `Button`? There is no `android:tint` for `Button`.

Comment: I dont know the scope of this operation but I had a problem in Activity scope; when I replace Fragments, tint change doesnt invalidate. I solved my issue with `imageView.setColorFilter`

Comment: Even if you have only one path, tint changes both fill AND stroke.

Answer (score 8):

There are several ways of doing the same stuff, but this works for both **Vector Drawables** as well as **SVG** (Local/Network).

```
imageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, 
R.color.headPink), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

(change R.color.headPink with color of your choice)

Comment: The question is about changing the color of a specific element, not the whole drawable.

Answer (score 5):

You **can** change the color of individual path at runtime, without using reflection.

VectorMaster introduces dynamic control over vector drawables. Each and every aspect of a vector drawable can be controlled dynamically (via Java instances), using this library.

Just add the following dependency in your app's build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.sdsmdg.harjot:vectormaster:1.0.9'
}
```

In your case you need a simple color change:

**Vector example: your_vector.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:name="outline"
    android:pathData="M20.84,4..."
    android:strokeColor="#5D5D5D"
    android:fillColor="#00000000"
    android:strokeWidth="2"/>
```

**XML**:

```
<com.sdsmdg.harjot.vectormaster.VectorMasterView
    android:id="@+id/your_vector"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    app:vector_src="@drawable/your_drawable" />
```

**Java**:

```
VectorMasterView heartVector = (VectorMasterView) 
findViewById(R.id.your_drawable);

// find the correct path using name
PathModel outline = heartVector.getPathModelByName("outline");

// set the stroke color
outline.setStrokeColor(Color.parseColor("#ED4337"));

// set the fill color (if fill color is not set or is TRANSPARENT, then no fill is drawn)
outline.setFillColor(Color.parseColor("#ED4337"));
```

From: https://github.com/harjot-oberai/VectorMaster, licensed under MIT.

You have now full control over vector drawables.

Comment: Very nice. My svg doesn't use names and it would be inpractical to edit and add names by hand.Iis it possible getPathModel by index in array?

Comment: You can but you need at least a group name: the group containing your paths, e.g:  `GroupModel groupModel = getVectorMasterDrawable().getGroupModelByName("groupName"); 
ArrayList<PathModel> pathModelArrayList = groupModel.getPathModels();`

Comment: @JeRoll, By any chance I can get a `Drawable` after setting the path color, at present I set the `imageview` as hidden and taken `drawable = imageView.getDrawable()`

Comment: Note that VectorMaster doesn't render some VectorDrawable resources well: https://github.com/harjot-oberai/VectorMaster/issues/32

Answer (score 3):

You can use this method to change color in lower API to change vector color in fragment

```
int myVectorColor = ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorBlack);
                    myButton.getIcon().setColorFilter(myVectorColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

in place of getActivity you should use MainActivity.this for changing vector color in activity

Comment: The question is about changing the color of a specific element, not the whole drawable.

Answer (score 2):

Check my answer on this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38418049/1335438.

It is a great idea on how to manage this by using Themes and parameterizing the paths in order to be able to set them dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Eyal in this post 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32007436/4969047

You **cannot** change the color of individual path at runtime.
Looking at the source code of `VectorDrawableCompat`, the only method to expose the inner element by name is `getTargetByName` which is present in inner **private** state class `VectorDrawableCompatState` of `VectorDrawableCompat`.

Since it is a package private (default) - you can't use it (unless you use [reflection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/private-fields-and-methods.html)).

Comment: @Shubral, can you please elaborate with code on how reflection can be used to achieve this? It may take time but would help loads of people.

Comment: I actually tried to use reflection, and even though I've succeeded reaching the function, it returned just null... Can you please show how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through Java reflection.
First reflect call VectorDrawable.getTargetByName or VectorDrawableCompat.getTargetByName method to get VFullPath:

```
Object path = ReflectUtil.invoke(vectorDrawable, "getTargetByName", new Class[]{String.class}, new Object[]{pathName});
```

Then Reflect calls the VFullPath.setFillColor method to set the color:

```
ReflectUtil.invoke(path, "setFillColor", new Class[]{int.class}, new Object[]{color});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
DrawableCompat.setTint(imageView.getDrawable(),ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorAccent));
```