# How to set ImageView's tint under (Expandable)ListAdapter?

Tags: java, android, android-vectordrawable

## Preamble

I've been g00gling for half an hour now, and it seems like I'm really missing something important.

> **Note:** I've already tried the solutions for these questions
>
> [How to change color of vector drawable path on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35625099/how-to-change-color-of-vector-drawable-path-on-button-click)
>   [How to set tint for an image view programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121938/how-to-set-tint-for-an-image-view-programmatically-in-android)
>   [Changing ImageView source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974862/changing-imageview-source)
>
> These solutions either recolor *ALL* ImageView srcs or they don't do anything at all (vector remains black).

My drawable is a vector asset from the material icons directory:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2z" />
</vector>
```

My ImageView:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gradeBullet"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="25.5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25.5dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/importantgrade" />
```

I would like to do this with *Compat, because I'd also like to support earlier APIs (API>17).

My ImageView: `ImageView gradeBullet = convertView.findViewById(R.id.gradeBullet);`

## Try I.

MyAmazingAdapter.java - `getChildView(...)`

```
gradeBullet.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, gradeObj.colorId), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Result: Does nothing.

## Try II.

MyAmazingAdapter.java - `getChildView(...)`

```
DrawableCompat.setTint(gradeBullet.getDrawable(), ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.myColor));
```

Result: Recolors everything.

## Try III.

MyAmazingAdapter.java - `getChildView(...)`

```
VectorDrawableCompat drawable = (VectorDrawableCompat) gradeBullet.getDrawable();
drawable.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, gradeObj.colorId));
gradeBullet.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Result: Gives a weird color. (Definitely not what I want, it's closer to the original color)

## Try IV.

All the above with a `final` to the gradeBullet, got the same results.

## Some other info

- The `gradeObj.colorId` is different for *every* childView.
- Using shapes and `setColor` instead of SVG is **not** what I want.
- Currently only tested with API lvl 26
- MyAmazingAdapter.java extends `BaseExpandableListAdapter`

If you'd like more info, just mention it in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try your first method with `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN` or `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP` instead of `PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY`.

[PorterDuff.mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are welcome , i add documentation link for more explanations :)