# AndroidX BottomAppBar navigation icon color

Tags: android, material-design, androidx, material-components-android, android-bottomappbar

I've defined a bottom bar in a layout like that:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_black_24dp" />
```

The navigation icon is a generic icon generated from the "new vector drawable" wizard. Is there a way to apply a tint to it?

The bottom bar is not the activity action bar.

What I've tried so far:

- applied a theme with an overridden `textColorPrimary` color
- applied a theme with an overridden `controlColorNormal` color

If there's a solution that also works on icons supplied by loading a menu from XML (using `inflateMenu()` or `replaceMenu()`), that would be perfect.

Comment: by applying tint you mean to change the color of the vector image using code or while generating the image?

Comment: [You can try this solution for changing the color of vector image.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35625099/how-to-change-color-of-vector-drawable-path-on-button-click/36400463)

Answer (score 2):

The navigation icon color is bases on `colorControlNormal` attribute.
You can override it using:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.BottomAppBar"
```

with:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.BottomAppBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/....</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For programmatically changing color of the navigation icon insert into your activity 'onCreate()' this code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   ...
   if (myIsLightTheme)
       bottomBar.navigationIcon?.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
   else 
       bottomBar.navigationIcon?.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
   ...
}
```