# BottomAppBar with BottomNavigationView: Cant change icon and text color

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-bottomappbar, android-bottomnavigationview

I have a BottomAppBar with nested BottomNaviagtionView that looks like this. I can't seem to override the default purple color for when the selected icon is chosen.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorWhite"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_transparent"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_app_bar"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"
        app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false" />
</com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/redyellow"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    /> </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Steps I have tried:

1. A few different themed style variations in the styles.xml file with no luck...[similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62842893/7516413)
2. Then I created a custom drawable file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
       <item android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"  />
    </selector>
```

And then apply that to the `app:itemIconTint="@color/..."` & `app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_colors"` but that didn't seem to work either.

Here is the rest of my code:

styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="actionBarSize">70dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="bottom_nav_overlay">
        <!-- selected item -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorSecondary</item>
        <!-- other -->
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
    // For control over item selection of both touch and mouse driven selection
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0-rc01"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.yarolegovich:discrete-scrollview:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0"
```

nav_item_colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:alpha="1.0"
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:color="@color/colorSecondary" />
    <item
        android:alpha="0.6"
        android:state_checked="false"
        android:color="@android:color/black"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **`itemIconTint`** and **`itemTextColor`** attributes in the `BottomNavigationView`:

```
   <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
           app:itemIconTint="@color/..."
           app:itemTextColor="@color/..."/>
```

Using a selector like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:alpha="1.0" android:color="@color/..." android:state_checked="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.6" android:color="@color/..."/>
</selector>
```

[image]

Otherwise you can override the color using:

```
   <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
       android:theme="@style/bottom_nav_overlay"/>
```

with:

```
<style name="bottom_nav_overlay">
    <!-- selected item -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/...</item>
    <!-- other -->
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/...</item>
</style>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: So I have tried this solution and it shows up correctly in the XML preview with those colors. But when the emulator runs it reverses back to the default black with selected purple. The same thing happens when I run it on my Samsung.

Comment: @cpfleck Are you using the 1.1.0 of material components or higher? Post your code, there is something that changes the theme.

Comment: I've edited my question to include more of my code. Let me know if there's something else you need to see. Thanks!

Comment: @cpfleck You are using an AppCompat theme but the material components library requires a [MaterialComponentsTheme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#material-components-themes).

Comment: Ok so I tried updating my theme with different material components themes and also the bridge ones. The only thing that changed was my logo FAB turned black. the default purple and black still remained for the icons.

Comment: @cpfleck Remove also the colorAccent (replaced by colorSecondary). But what color in your app theme is purple?

Comment: I have no idea, I haven't specified purple anywhere in my styles.xml, colors.xml, or programmatically in my MainActivity.java

Comment: Very silly error on my part. I have fixed it now. I was working in a duplicated file and didn't realise.... Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm able to change bottomNavigation icon and text color into desired color

Inside `BottomNavigationView`

```
 app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
 app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
```

**bottom_navigation_colors:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:color="@color/dark_red" />
    <item
        android:state_checked="false"
        android:color="@color/black" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Use `@color/bottom_navigation_colors` instead of `@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors`

Comment: So this shows up correctly in the XML preview as well but when ran on the emulator or phone it reverts back to default.