# Precise control over Androids VectorDrawable animations

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation, vector-graphics, android-vectordrawable

**UPDATE:** Solution found! Scroll down for my accepted answer!

I want to animate multiple elements of one image and link the animation to ViewPagers position (so multiple elements are morphing or flying in/out depending on the current page being dragged).

So, is there a way to precisely control the current frame of the animation? For example let's assume i have this set:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="800"
        android:propertyName="scaleY"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="1" />
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="800"
        android:propertyName="scaleX"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="1" />
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="800"
        android:propertyName="rotation"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="360" />
</set>
```

Animated vector file:

```
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/pre_signup_1" >
    <target
        android:name="plus_button"
        android:animation="@anim/pre_signup_1_plus_container" />
    <target
        android:name="plus"
        android:animation="@anim/pre_signup_1_plus_sign" />
</animated-vector>
```

Java code to run the animation:

```
ImageView mImage1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_1);
AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat animated = (AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat) mImage1.getDrawable();

animated.start();
```

Is there a way to control the animation like `setCurrentDuration(400)` which will presumably set the current state of the animation to it's half? Maybe there is a way to split that vector drawable into layers and animate them programmatically? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like it is possible to access paths and groups inside `VectorDrawableCompat` and animate/morph them however you want!

After a some research I ended up duplicating the following classes from the `android.support.graphics.drawable` package: `AndroidResources`, `PathParser`, `TypedArrayUtils`, `VectorDrawableCommon` and `VectorDrawableCompat`.

Next we need to make the following method and classes public inside of the `VectorDrawableCompat` class: `getTargetByName`, `VGroup` and `VFullPath`.

Next in the `VectorDrawableCompat` class remove the block that checks for Android version (`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23`). Don't know why, but if you don't do it, the animating won't work on android API 23 and up (need more research).

I may have missed a couple of private methods, but it's just a matter of making them public if you run into problems.

So, now we have access to the layers of our `VectorDrawable`! Here is a small example of scaling a vector group depending on the `ViewPager`'s position:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="276dp"
    android:height="359dp"
    android:viewportWidth="276"
    android:viewportHeight="359">

    <group
        android:pivotX="205.5"
        android:pivotY="214.5"
        android:name="my_group">
        <path
            android:strokeColor="#4D394B"
            android:strokeWidth="7"
            android:strokeLineJoin="bevel"
            android:fillColor="#1ED761"
            android:pathData="M206.5,180 C186.9,180,171,195.9,171,215.5 S186.9,251,206.5,251
C226.1,251,242,235.1,242,215.5 S226.1,180,206.5,180 Z" />
        <path
            android:fillColor="#4D394B"
            android:pathData="M210,211 L210,190 L202,190 L202,211 L181,211 L181,219 L202,219 L202,241 L210,241
L210,219 L232,219 L232,211 Z" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

And this is the code used to animate the group:

```
ImageView myImageView;
VectorDrawableCompat.VGroup myVectorGroup;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

    myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_1);

    VectorDrawableCompat vectorDrawable = VectorDrawableCompat.create(getResources(), R.drawable.my_vector_drawable, null);
    vectorDrawable.setAllowCaching(false); // Important to allow image updates
    myVectorGroup = (VectorDrawableCompat.VGroup) vectorDrawable.getTargetByName("my_group");

    myImageView.setImageDrawable(vectorDrawable);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            if(myVectorGroup != null && position < 1) {
                myVectorGroup.setScaleX(1f - positionOffset);
                myVectorGroup.setScaleY(1f - positionOffset);

                myImageView.invalidate();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I need some more testing to determine compatibility, but it works for now!

Comment: Not tried this yet, but nice work. It's a shame the AnimatedVectorDrawable is missing this ability out the box.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm talking about! :( I use this possibility all over the place now and with really complex animations! And it's quite fast even on older devices!

Comment: @Arthur I don't see any code to interpolate path data after you modified the existing code for vectorDrawable. Can you please share the whole code to clearly understand how you achieved pathData morph in pre lollipop device i.e API 15 above

Comment: @AftabAli Hi! If you need to morph one shape to another you need both shapes to have the same number of commands (they should be drawn using same vertices in you vector software). After that you can use `getPathData` from `VPath` which will return all the commands for needed path. Then you need to call `interpolatePathDataNode` on each path node from the array and morph it accordingly.

Comment: i must to say "Thank you very much!" Big thanks for tricks. It's worked for me!

Comment: Android Support Library v26.1.0 doesn't have `VectorDrawableCompat.VGroup`

Comment: @VipulAsri Well, since you are not using it directly (but rather making a copy and modifying it) you can copy the classes from an older version of the support library

Comment: From what I read, it is still impossible to control AnimatedVectorDrawable current state like `setCurrentDuration(400)`. You can only `setScale()`, `setRotation()` or `setTranslate()`. You can't force animation current state for example based on swipe progress.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can't do this with the **AnimatedVectorDrawable/AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat** programmatically.

A workaround is to use a [Level List drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LevelList) and animate its **levels**:
but you'll need lots of images for the levels to simulate the smooth transition, I'm using just three levels here for demonstration.

First you'll define the drawable level list like this:**res/drawable/my_level_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/level0"
    android:maxLevel="0"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/level1"
        android:maxLevel="1"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/level2"
        android:maxLevel="2"/>
</level-list>
```

Then in the layout file:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/my_level_list" />
```

Then in your activity:

```
int MIN_LEVEL=0;
int MAX_LEVEL=2;

ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);

Drawable myLevelSetDrawable= img.getDrawable();
ObjectAnimator anim=ObjectAnimator.ofInt(myLevelSetDrawable,"level",MIN_LEVEL,MAX_LEVEL);
anim.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
AnimatorSet set=new AnimatorSet();
set.play(anim);
set.setDuration(1000);
set.start();
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the documentation says for AnimatedVectorDrawables there is no way to track the state of animation or to jump into any state other than animationStart and animationEnd.

You may have to use a custom solution to achieve this effect. [This blog post](http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2015/04/09/advanced-transitions-with-vector-drawable/) explains a way using Android’s widget state tracking to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: Maybe there is another way to animate objects back and forth? I don't mean vector groups, but maybe separate `ImageView`s?