# How to control the progress of an AnimatedVectorDrawable in Android?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-vectordrawable

I would like to control or bind the progress of an AnimatedVectorDrawable with a view pager.

Is it possible to control programatically the progress of the animation or bind it to a view pager like it's done with the Swipe-To-Refresh or the Navigation drawer controls?

[image: Swipe-To-Refresh control]
[image: Navigation drawer control]

Comment: It's not part of the AnimatedVectorDrawable functionality at the moment, but see this post for someone's attempt at doing it themselves: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37621687/5251523