# How can you programmatically show groups of an AnimatedVectorDrawable?

Tags: android, vector, android-animation, android-vectordrawable, animatedvectordrawable

I am trying to animate groups inside my AnimatedVectorDrawable without them reseting after each is shown. The id provided is my animation for each group, but when called a second time the first group is lost. Any Ideas?

```
            animationView.setBackgroundResource(id);
            animationDrawable = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) animationView.getBackground();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                animationDrawable.start();
            }
```

Comment: Can you provide more code?

Comment: I'm currently reviewing this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28790985/programmatically-update-android-vector-drawable

Comment: I think I am going to do this with a GridView instead, even with the mentioned library I am having trouble selecting the proper targetByName.

Comment: Yes, I'm surprised as the limitations in Android on this issue.  From what I have read, Android has the methods to access interior groups in SVG objects but the methods are declared private and inaccessible.  Its a shame as SVG is a great way to pre-build complicated shapes and object.  There's gotta be a better way.