# How to change stroke color and fillColor for Vector Drawable programmatically?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I want to dynamically change stroke and fill color of predefined vector drawable icon used as map marker.

Function to change color of vector drawable:

```
 private fun bitmapDescriptorFromVector(context: Context, vectorResId: Int, strokeColor: Int, tintColor: Int): BitmapDescriptor? {
        val vectorDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, vectorResId)
        return vectorDrawable?.let {
            vectorDrawable.setBounds(
                0,
                0,
                vectorDrawable.intrinsicWidth,
                vectorDrawable.intrinsicHeight
            )
            vectorDrawable.mutate()
            vectorDrawable.setTint(tintColor)
            val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                vectorDrawable.intrinsicWidth,
                vectorDrawable.intrinsicHeight,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
            )
            val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
            vectorDrawable.draw(canvas)
            return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)
        }
    }
```

vector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid android:color="@color/app_white"/>

    <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="@color/app_blue"/>

    <size
        android:width="16dp"
        android:height="16dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: It [seems like you cannot change that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28790985/programmatically-update-android-vector-drawable). You could use a `ColorMatrixColorFilter` and in the xml file make the stroke completely red and the solid completely green to multiply these values using a `ColorMatrix` that weights red and green for a new color channel according to the channel's corresponding value in `strokeColor` and `tintColor`divided by 255f. Note: You won't be able to use `setTint` anymore as they both use color filters.