# Is there a way to listen for Animatable.isRunning changing?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-vectordrawable

I have been trying to make something happen after an `AnimatedVectorDrawable` is done animating and I was looking at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28812604/is-there-a-way-to-listen-for-animation-end-in-animatedvectordrawables) regarding the `AVDWrapper`, but I have a gut feeling that there is a more elegant way.

Namely, setting a boolean change listener to check if `anim.isRunning()` has changed. I have been following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457711/android-listening-for-variable-changes) and it's answers and have set up a boolean change listener (pretty much exactly the same way and `setBoo` to `anim.isRunning()`) but it's not working. Am I understanding something conceptually wrong here? The observer pattern should trigger at the end of the animation when `anim.isRunning()` changes from `true` to `false`. Or is it because an animation is time sensitive/continuous and needs to be continuously polled, therefore this won't work? How about if the listener implements `Runnable`?

Thank you.

Comment: tried to override `registerAnimationCallback`?

Comment: I'm looking at it right now, but I'm not sure how I would go about it without an example. But I'm guessing the callback calls back to the boolean listener?

Comment: sorry not override (when writing i was thinking about different post), just call it with a custom callback

Comment: I see, I'll try it. I'm actually using the support library that allows `AnimatedVectorDrawables` to be used with lower APIs. Would this break the compatability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom `Animatable2.AnimationCallback` and call `anim.registerAnimationCallback()`.