# Return animation / new animation

Tags: android, animation, animatedvectordrawable

I have `animated-vector` inside included in `ImageView` usind `android:src`. I am using this code in onClick to launch an animation:

```
Drawable drawable = element.getDrawable();
if (drawable instanceof Animatable) {
    ((Animatable) drawable).start();
}
```

Simple enough.

However, I want this animation to 'return' to the previous state in onclick. Scenario: Play/Stop. When user clicks play, play is animated to stop. When user clicks again, stop is animated to play. I have both `animated-vector` drawables, however I can't find a way how to do this. I believe it should be possible but I did not find a simple way. I have found only [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28910678/1619036) with creating wrappers, running threads to detect animation end etc.