# Difference between SVG and VectorDrawable in Android

Tags: android, svg, android-vectordrawable

While Android supports SVG, why should it be converted to VectorDrawable?

This code example shows SVG in Android:

```
SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.android);
imageView.setImageDrawable(svg.createPictureDrawable());
```

Comment: VectorDrawable is a **subset** of SVG. It only parses the `path` syntax of the SVG format specs.

Comment: SVG is not supported out-of-the-box

Comment: `This code example shows svg in android:` ... if you install a 3rd party library.

Comment: please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35738726/2826147) answer.

Answer (score 8):

The SVGParser functionality you mention is a third party implementation of SVG support for Android.

The major problems with using SVG in Android are:

- SVG files may be very complex and can be very slow to render
- All the third party implementations I have used have had bugs and failed to load or render some SVG files correctly
- Most of the third party implementations have been abandoned and none 
  seem to be actively maintained

I have written more about using SVG files in Android and the available third party libraries in the following article:

https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/02/27/vector-graphics-in-android-part-1-svg/

VectorDrawable supports of subset of SVG format that is designed to ensure it is fast to render. I have written about VectorDrawable and how to convert your existing SVG files to VectorDrawable [here](https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/03/18/vector-graphics-in-android-converting-svg-to-vectordrawable/).

Answer (score 2):

> While android supports SVG

No, it does not, other than via `WebView` or third-party SVG rendering libraries.

> Why we should convert SVG to VectorDrawble?

You are welcome to show SVG files via `WebView` or third-party SVG rendering libraries. `VectorDrawable` is an option; it is not a requirement.

> This code example shows svg in android:

There is no `SVGParser` class in the Android SDK.