# How to put a svg file in your app?

Tags: android, svg

I would like to insert a svg picture in my app so I looked for in Youtube ans I follow this tutorial :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S65WtImJOvI

I create a directory by the name of raw, I download svg-android.jar and I added the following lines in my MainActivity.java :

```
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.android);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(svg.createPictureDrawable());
        setContentView(imageView);
```

The svg picture is android.svg. But when I tried to compile and execute with an emulator it crashes ! The app does not open !

So, May I have to do something in the activity_main.xml ?

What do you think about this ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Would you be able to paste the logs?

Comment: Do you just want to show svg images in like `ImageViews`?

Comment: When posting questions on stackoverflow always ask yourself: "Did i provide enough information so someone can figure out what is wrong?" In this case the answer would be "No. Maybe i should post the stack trace at least"

Comment: I have this warning : "too much output to process". Yes absolutely I just want to show my svg image

Comment: But indeed what I want is to use svg file not for instance a jpg file because it is not a vectorial image you see ?

Comment: you can convert it into a .xml file using the _Vector Asset_. This is much more easier to handle

Comment: What is the Android version of the device you're trying to launch your app on?

Comment: It is Android 7.0

Comment: Is there any reason why you are adding your svg file dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

Easy,

Add it like this, and use inside of ImageView

`app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person_outline_black_24dp"`

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Default Android ImageView does not support SVG files. You can include a custom library to perform this operation.

This is a wonderfull library I've used so far : https://github.com/Pixplicity/sharp

Answer (score -1):

The easier way is to transform your SVG into a XML vector image (using [this website](http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/) for example).
Then you can use it almost like a standard resource drawable.
For example in your xml layout, on an ImageView, you'll have to use `app:srcCompat` instead of `android:src`.

You may have to add `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in your gradle file too.

Comment: Please note that **SVG != VectorDrawable**. The latter derives from the former, but represent only a **limited subset** of it.

Comment: @Rotwang You seem to have given the same answer 2y ago to this post (https://stackoverflow.com/q/31926212/1827254), can you please develop or share a link as I'm interested to know more about that?

Comment: This isn't and it wasn't an answer. Just a comment (still valid). Commonsware answered. You can google for svg file format and see how much more complex it is in regards of VectorDrawables.

Comment: I've found this article (https://medium.com/@nandankaushik/android-working-with-vectordrawable-can-we-easily-convert-svg-to-vectordrawable-e4000143b13f). But if you don't use things like gradient, for most of the cases a VectorDrawable is enough and, like that, you don't need to embedded an external library to display your SVG.

Comment: Well, if you only need paths and no text, no gradients, no primitives, ... that's fine.