# Using AnimatedVectorDrawable causing cut to icon Android

Tags: android, svg, hamburger-menu, android-vectordrawable

Pre starting I'd like to tell that I'm using [Vect Align](https://github.com/bonnyfone/vectalign) library to morph the two images

**The Icons**

The start icon (SVG): https://storage.googleapis.com/material-icons/external-assets/v1/icons/svg/ic_menu_white_24px.svg

The end icon (SVG): https://storage.googleapis.com/material-icons/external-assets/v1/icons/svg/ic_close_white_24px.svg

**The Path generated by Vect Align**

Start path (drawer_path):
`M 3.0,18.0 l 18.0,0.0 l 0.0,-2.0 l -18.0,0.0 l 0.0,2.0 L 3.0,18.0 m 0.0,-5.0 l 18.0,0.0 l 0.0,-2.0 l -18.0,0.0 l 0.0,2.0 L 3.0,13.0 M 3.0,6.0 L 3.0,6.0 L 3.0,6.0 L 3.0,6.0 L 3.0,6.0 L 3.0,6.0 L 3.0,8.0 L 21.0,8.0 L 21.0,6.0 L 3.0,6.0 L 3.0,6.0`

End path (close_path):
`M 19.0,6.41 l 0.0,0.0 l 0.0,0.0 l 0.0,0.0 l 0.0,0.0 L 17.59,5.0 m 0.0,0.0 l0.0,0.0 l 0.0,0.0 l 0.0,0.0 l 0.0,0.0 L 12.0,10.59 M 12.0,10.59 L 6.41,5.0 L 5.0,6.41 L 10.59,12.0 L 5.0,17.59 L 6.41,19.0 L 12.0,13.41 L 17.59,19.0 L 19.0,17.59 L 13.41,12.0 L 19.0,6.41`

**Screenshot of the issue**
[image: device-2015-11-05-164520]

**XML Files in the Project:**

Vector File (ic_drawer.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">

    <path
        android:name="v"
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="@string/drawer_path" />

</vector>
```

Animated Vector File (ic_drawer_to_close.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_drawer">

    <target
        android:name="v"
        android:animation="@anim/drawer_to_close" />

</animated-vector>
```

The Anim File (drawer_to_close.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="650"
    android:propertyName="pathData"
    android:valueFrom="@string/drawer_path"
    android:valueTo="@string/close_path"
    android:valueType="pathType" />
```

I hope someone helps me with this issue.

Comment: This does seem like weird behaviour, I've pinpointed the problem to the bolded part here     End path (close_path): M 19.0,6.41 l 0.0,0.0 l 0.0,0.0 l 0.0,0.0 l 0.0,0.0 L 17.59,5.0 **m 0.0,0.0** l0.0,0.0 l 0.0,0.0 l 0.0,0.0 l 0.0,0.0 L 12.0,10.59 M 12.0,10.59 L 6.41,5.0 L 5.0,6.41 L 10.59,12.0 L 5.0,17.59 L 6.41,19.0 L 12.0,13.41 L 17.59,19.0 L 19.0,17.59 L 13.41,12.0 L 19.0,6.41    but I don't know why it's doing that or the best way for you to fix it

Comment: please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35738726/2826147) answer.