# How to create vector drawables for android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, svg, android-vectordrawable

I am new to `VectorDrawables`.

I can see that the default `vector drawables` provided with android studio like `ic_menu_gallery`, `ic_menu_camera`, etc. are working great. So I tried to create my own `vector drawables` by converting my `png images` to `svg` first and using the path and fill values to make vector drawables i.e replaced the `android:pathData` for d and `android:fillColor` for fill tag in svg files. It somehow gave vector drawables but distorted or currputed looking.

If I am not taking the right approach please suggest me.

Comment: please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35738726/2826147) answer.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can use Android Studio. 
Convert png to svg file online tools [PNG to SVG](http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg)
 [image: File - > New -> Vector Asset]

[image: You can choose Material Icon or Local SVG file]

For SVG color can use :

```
  <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_24dp"
    android:tint="@color/primary" />
```

Or

```
imageView.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Can convert SVG to PNG online tool:
[coolutils](https://www.coolutils.com/online/SVG-to-PNG#)

Convert SVG to Android drawable:
[inloop](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/)

Comment: how to change color (without RGB color) under v21 as ?attr/colorPrimary

Comment: Perhaps anyone can help... I am trying to convert ibb.co/SdZjjTH to xml using autotracer.org and inloop.github.io/svg2android. It works, but when I try to use it in my app, the app crashes. Can you check if it works for you? Thanks!

Answer (score 44):

Here is the best method to convert any png/jpg into vector drawable:

1. Download the software [InkScape](https://inkscape.org/en/download/)
2. Open your png in it and follow the procedure shown in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bD29KTVHht4) to convert it to svg
3. The use the [SVG to Vector Drawable tool](http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/) to convert the svg to vector drawable. The other tool svg2android does not always work as sometimes the svg gets improperly converted to a vector drawable
4. Copy the code into a new drawable resource file. Now this can be used as a regular drawable.

If you already have a svg then start straightaway from step 3.

Comment: @KirillKarmazin, I am not the creator of the tutorial. I too learned from it.

Answer (score 22):

I had this problem too and found this very useful website:

https://materialdesignicons.com/

There are many icons and with the "advanced export" you can edit the settings easily.
For me it was the fastest and easiest way to create vector drawable, if you don't want to download the file, you can just view the code and copy it, not only as a vector drawable but even as an SVG or XAML.
Oh and it's free:)

1. Pick an icon
2. Click on Advanced Export
3. Edit the settings
4. Click on "View Vector Drawable" or download it and put it in your project:)

Comment: it saves me lot of time

Answer (score 6):

**Step 1**
The first step is to convert it into SVG format
- For black and white SVG convertor there are many tools but there are very few good tools for coloured conversion. https://www.autotracer.org/ is one of the best and it worked for me. Convert and download the SVG file.
**Step 2**- In the ' Android Studio ' Go to drawables folder and right click to select New - Vector Asset

**Step 3** - Choose the downloaded SVG file from Step 1. The android Studio

**Step 4** - Dont forget to set navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null); as null in case the coloured icons are being used in a navigation drawer/view.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 5):

In Android Studio 3.1:

<kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>New</kbd> -> <kbd>Vector Asset</kbd>

Asset Type: Select Local File

Click on the path to choose a .svg or a .psd file

If you don't have an image, go to Google Images, Advanced Image Search.
Use file Type: SVG files

Answer (score 2):

you can create your own svg image or icon using photoshop/illustrator and can import vector asset (available in android studio 2.+). some times importing it results distorted image if svg is complex or has many elements then you can use it as single single element as vector assets by overlapping ImageViews.

Answer (score 2):

Try this : 
Step 1: Drawable > New > Vector Asset

[image]

Select clip art ( to use existing icon)
Select from local file 
choose and add.You can add the color icon in sane way.

Answer (score 1):

**Android Studio create vector drawables**

You can  use Asset Studio to  do it

```
File -> New -> Vector Asset -> Configure
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this was the first question I found while trying to solve a bug in my project, I will add what was my solution.

Ensure the vector drawable was added as an XML file in the drawables folder. I added it as an SVG drawable, which was not recognized in the code.

If it is in SVG, change the extension to XML and it will work.