# How do I convert pngs directly to android vector drawables?

Tags: android, png, android-vectordrawable

Are there online tools to convert png file to vector drawable files (xml in Android)?

I have few pngs that I was using for icons & various places in my app.
So, now I want to convert them to xmls. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: you don't. That is not how Android handles png. XML drawables are custom drawable files that you write, like shapes, colors, etc more like a custom view. You need to generate assets with your PNG. Use this -> https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/. Also it would be great if you elaborate on your query.

Comment: I have edited my query.
Also, I am not able to convert my png to vector drawable using the above link.
https://github.com/project-travel-mate/Travel-Mate/blob/master/Android/app/src/main/res/drawable/aed.png

Comment: Try the solution I provided below. hopefully it helps

Comment: This does not really make sense except for very, very few exceptions. The reason has nothing to do with Android, but with how graphic formats work. Converting a raster graphic format into a vector format simply does not make sense. It will produce an output, but that output will have none of the benefits of a vector graphic. It cannot be scaled like a _real_ vector graphic but it is equally expensice to draw. That does not make sense.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Ok, so you can convert PNG to Android vector drawable following these steps

- Step 1: 
  Convert PNG to SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics)

https://www.autotracer.org/

Or you can use any online converter of your choice

- Step 2:
  Use the generated SVG in step 1 and convert it to Android vector drawable using this link
  http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/

http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/

Alternatively you can also use Android studio to generate Vector drawables from SVG generated in Step 1.

- Inside Android studio, right click on your drawable folder
  New > Vector Asset

This will open up the Android studio Vector asset generator. 
Select a local SVG file (the one you generated online)

[image]

You can also refer to this post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35402459/6142219

Comment: This png to svg convert is by far the best one, already had tried a lot of different options and this one is in a total different league! Very glad to found this answer!

Comment: @ggrana Perhaps you can help me... I am trying to convert https://ibb.co/SdZjjTH to xml using https://www.autotracer.org/ and http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/. It works, but when I try to use it in my app, the app crashes. Can you check if it works for you? Thanks!