# How to use vector drawables with View besides ImageView with srcCompat?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-vectordrawable

`app:srcCompat` with `ImageView` allows for backward compatible use of vector drawables. But how can you use them with other `View`s besides `ImageView`? For example, the `TextView` attributes like `android:drawableLeft`.

Also using the vector drawable as an `android:icon` with `MenuItem` caused a crash with the following exception:

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.setActionView(MenuItemImpl.java:621)
   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.setActionView(MenuItemImpl.java:40)
   at android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat.setActionView(MenuItemCompat.java:310)
   at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:465)
   at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:479)
   at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:196)
   at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:118)
   at com.example.niceapp.context.main.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:101)
   at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2578)
```

With Support Library 23.2.0, how can this issue be addressed?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For AppCompat version 23.3.0 where no work solution via selector XML (razzledazzle's accepted answer) we can do this by programmatically:

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnEnter"
    />
```

MainActivity.java

```
AppCompatImageButton image = (AppCompatImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnEnter);
if (image != null) {
    VectorDrawableCompat vcAccept = VectorDrawableCompat.create(getResources(), R.drawable.vc_accept, getTheme());
    VectorDrawableCompat vcAcceptWhite = VectorDrawableCompat.create(getResources(), R.drawable.vc_accept_white, getTheme());

    StateListDrawable stateList = new StateListDrawable();
    stateList.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused, -android.R.attr.state_pressed}, vcAccept);
    stateList.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused, android.R.attr.state_pressed}, vcAcceptWhite);
    stateList.addState(new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_focused, android.R.attr.state_pressed}, vcAcceptWhite);
    stateList.addState(new int[]{}, vcAccept);

    image.setImageDrawable(stateList);
}
```

This code is equivalent for this selector xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/vc_accept" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/vc_accept_white" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/vc_accept_white" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/vc_accept" />
</selector>
```

---

#### UPDATE

If the vector drawable is not shown using API 23, you'll need to convert the `VectorDrawable` to a regular `Drawable` first. If you want to use `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` you'll need to do this, but for StateListDrawable I didn't need to.

```
Drawable icon;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    icon = VectorDrawableCompat.create(getResources(), R.drawable.vc_icon, getContext().getTheme());
} else {
    icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.vc_icon, getContext().getTheme());
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Setting the vector drawable with setImageResource did not work in my Adapter. Creating a VectorDrawableCompat of it and setting it as ImageDrawable worked perfectly!

Answer (score 45):

**Update 2**: They have added an option to enable it again in Support Library 23.4.0:

> For AppCompat users, we’ve added an opt-in API to re-enable support Vector Drawables from resources (the behavior found in 23.2) via [AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate.html#setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled%28boolean%29) - keep in mind that this still can cause issues with memory usage and problems updating Configuration instances, hence why it is disabled by default.

**Update**:
This no longer works starting from version 23.3.0

> For AppCompat users, we’ve decided to remove the functionality which
>   let you use vector drawables from resources on pre-Lollipop devices
>   due to issues found in the implementation in version 23.2.0/23.2.1
>   [https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205236, https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=204708]. Using app:srcCompat
>   and setImageResource() continues to work.

From [Android Developers Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/iTDmFiGrVne)

---

> Using AppCompat and app:srcCompat is the most foolproof method of integrating vector drawables into your app.

That quote is from the official [blogpost](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) for the release of version 23.2.0 of the Support Library.

The post also mentions the following:

> You’ll find directly referencing vector drawables outside of `app:srcCompat` will fail prior to Lollipop. However, `AppCompat` does support loading vector drawables when they are referenced in another drawable container such as a `StateListDrawable`, `InsetDrawable`, `LayerDrawable`, `LevelListDrawable`, and `RotateDrawable`. By using this indirection, you can use vector drawables in cases such as `TextView`’s `android:drawableLeft` attribute, which wouldn’t normally be able to support vector drawables.

This translates to the steps below:

**Step 1:**

Create or import a vector resource which you require for the app. For example, one can create a vector drawable for the search icon and name it `ic_action_search_vector.xml`

**Step 2:**

Create another proxy drawable resource for the vector drawable previously created. Say, for the previous `ic_action_search_vector.xml`, `ic_action_search.xml` can be created as a simple `StateListDrawable` which could contain the lines below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_search_vector"/>
</selector>
```

This step can be skipped if you have referenced the vector drawable from another drawable resource which you will use with your View.

**Step 3:**

Use the drawable resource (here, `ic_action_search.xml`) that refers to the vector drawable (`ic_action_search_vector.xml`) instead of the vector drawable directly. For a menu, it would look like:

```
<item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

This is the solution to that problem!

Comment: Hi, we can do this by programmatically for AppCompat version 23.3.0, see my answer please.

Answer (score 18):

**Vector drawables can be used pre-Lollipop in other places than `app:srcCompat`, but it comes with a price.**

I've made [this diagram](https://medium.com/@ferrand.d/can-you-and-should-you-use-vector-drawables-a-cheatsheet-32a2e1cc2ecf) to help (valid for Support Library 23.4.0 to - at least - 25.1.0).

[image: VectorDrawable cheatsheet]

Answer (score 6):

You can add Vector Drawable in TextView programmatically. Make use of **VectorDrawableCompat** inorder to add drawableLeft/ drawableRight /drawableTop/ drawableBottom/ drawableStart/ drawableEnd.

**Steps:**

i. If TextView is inside Activity:

```
TextView tvUserName= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.et_username_or_email);
VectorDrawableCompat drawableCompat=VectorDrawableCompat.create(getResources(), R.drawable.layer_list_ic_user, tvUserName.getContext().getTheme());
tvUserName.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(drawableCompat, null, null, null);
```

ii. If TextView is inside Fragment:

```
TextView tvUserName= (TextView )view.findViewById(R.id.et_username_or_email);
VectorDrawableCompat drawableCompat=VectorDrawableCompat.create(getActivity().getResources(), R.drawable.layer_list_ic_user, tvUserName.getContext().getTheme());
tvUserName.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(drawableCompat, null, null, null);
```

For more information on VectorDrawableCompat Refer this  [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawableCompat.html)

Comment: this is working, thank you but theme is compulsory to add?

Comment: @RuchaBhatt Yes, it's compulsory.

Comment: yes, i checked it, but u can pass null so it's fine. :)

Comment: @RuchaBhatt Happy to help & if you are using custom text view then it's good practice to use theme.

Comment: Thanks but this solution requires API 17+ (Jelly Bean MR1)

Answer (score 1):

Android 5.0 (API level 21) and higher provides vector drawable support. If your app has a minimum API level that is lower, Vector Asset Studio adds the vector drawable file to your project; also, at build time, Gradle creates PNG raster images at various resolutions. Gradle generates the PNG densities specified by the Domain Specific Language (DSL) generatedDensities property in a build.gradle file. To generate PNGs, the build system requires Android Plugin for Gradle 1.5.0 or higher.

This is not true if you include in your gradle
 vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

either set to false or remove the line completely and all your vectors will work as they were.  But for olders versions of android they will be able to rely on the converted PNG

Answer (score 1):

Form android studio 3.0.0 **android:src** is not support vector image and below 21 my get exception. use **app:srcCompat** for vector image. Keep all vector image files inside the **drawable** folder.

```
android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
 }
```

> And in application class define this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

> Now you can use your .xml file. Don't forget to user this link: **xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/counterValuePanel"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_cart_notify"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now you can use app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_cart_notify" but if you try to use in android:background or android:drawableLeft then you got "Error inflating" exception. For that create a new wrapped drawable .xml file, **ic_cart_notify** is vector icon.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_cart_notify"/>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dadou is right. So if you would like use selector for view with VectorDrawables you need to add:

```
    static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(trfor);
}
```

to every Activity where you want to use VectorDrawables on devices with versions below Android 5.

Answer (score 0):

> set vector drawable to side drawable in textview in android

**AppCompatTextView** [now](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/androidx-rn#2018-dec-03-appcompat) supports `app:drawableLeftCompat`, `app:drawableTopCompat`, `app:drawableRightCompat`, `app:drawableBottomCompat`, `app:drawableStartCompat` and `app:drawableEndCompat` compound drawables, supporting backported drawable types such as *VectorDrawableCompat*.

Include this in your gradle file

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
```

In your text view you can use

```
app:drawableLeftCompat
app:drawableStartCompat
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using new support library and all I have to do is:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
```

In Build.gradle file

```
 defaultConfig {

    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

Now Where ever you are using like fragment, activity or adapter use this as the first line in your class

```
static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

after that use like as we do before, something.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivMainNavigationIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Something.java

```
thumbIcon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.ic_check_circle_black_24dp));
```

or if you have drawable id needed to be set dynamically

```
thumbIcon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,drawableID));
```