# How to set VectorDrawable as an image for ImageView programmatically

Tags: android, imageview, android-vectordrawable

I want to set some **vectorDrawables** to a **ImageView** in Android Studio.

I can set png and jpg drawable easily but when i want to set VectorDrawable, it does not work on imageview.

```
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_home);
```

ic_home is VectorDrawable and this code doesn't work.

Comment: read https://blog.stylingandroid.com/vectordrawables-part-1/

Comment: I have answered here, may this help. you can change vector drawable now.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/42281780/4517450

Answer (score 148, accepted):

If you want to use vector drawables (less OR greater than API 21) just do the following:

Set the image programmatically (e.g. in your activity):

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_left_arrow_blue);
```

or by XML:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/your_vector_name"
```

In your app's `build.gradle` you need to include:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}
```

And for vector support for less then API 21, add the following to `onCreate`:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```

Comment: still doesn't work for KitKat, only for >= 5.1 it works ok with `setImageResource`

Comment: for KitKat this worked only https://stackoverflow.com/a/35918375/7767664

Comment: AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);  
solved my problem on Kitkat

Answer (score 26):

For those who want to load a vector drawable programmatically for other uses, such as setting a drawableLeft or otherwise, you can use:

```
Drawable drawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, drawableRes);
```

where the context is a AppCompatActivity.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't seen this AppCompatResources thingy before. The mess is getting worse by each SDK release.

Answer (score 18):

As per official [android developer blog](https://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html), no changes for setImageResource() method at runtime for vectorDrawables.

> If you’re changing drawables at runtime, you’ll be able to use the
>   same
>   [setImageResource()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html?utm_campaign=android_launch_supportlibrary23.2_022216&utm_source=anddev&utm_medium=blog#setImageResource(int))
>   method as before - no changes there. Using AppCompat and app:srcCompat
>   is the most foolproof method of integrating vector drawables into your
>   app.

For more details, check out this nice article [AppCompat — Age of the vectors](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.gz62mwa67) by Google Developer.

Answer (score 18):

if you are concerned with the backward compatibility then you should use `AppCompatImageView` instead of image view. go through the code below.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_about"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_vector_image"
    />
```

java

```
AppCompatImageView image = (AppCompatImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_about);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_vector_image);
```

below code need to add in  build.gradle

android { defaultConfig{ vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true } }

And it will serve the perspective of app:srcCompat.

Comment: No need for that, according to the documentation "This will automatically be used when you use ImageView in your layouts and the top-level activity / dialog is provided by appcompat. You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views."

So you can use just ImageView unless you are extending it.

Comment: @user924 I didn't specify that you can use ImageView as long as the activity extends AppCompatActivity. If yours doesn't, it's like you said.

Answer (score 3):

for Java Code use:

```
formate_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_text);//ic_text is a Vector Image
```

and for XML use:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/search_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ads:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_barcode" //for Vector Image
        tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a vector in recycler view I was using `img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_home)` which didn't worked properly like some other image get formed in some item of recycler view. Then I used `img.setImageDrawable(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_home))` this worked .

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton, 
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView,
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
```

instead of `ImageButton`, `ImageView` etc.

If vector type image is used. Mainly for custom views.

Answer (score -4):

Delete two folders form your drawable folder then rebuild your project it will work properly[image]