# setBackgroundResource programmatically for vector drawables

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I have an `Imageview` in which I have to set a background image from my adapter. 
Using `app:srcCompat` in the `xml` code makes the image appear as it should. However, what should I do if I have to do the same thing programmatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set VectorDrawable as an image for ImageView programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41098015/how-to-set-vectordrawable-as-an-image-for-imageview-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the srcCompat effect programmatically on your imageview use the  [setImageResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html?utm_campaign=android_launch_supportlibrary23.2_022216&utm_source=anddev&utm_medium=blog#setImageResource(int)) method