# Why the Active Android Library reports this error = Before Android 4.1, ... would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in Drawable

Tags: java, android, android-studio, activeandroid

I use the **Active Android** Library, and every time I launch it, it will be displayed to me in the Logcat (Android Studio) , **Error Type = Warning**

**Picture of the complete program error**

[image]

- I also want to know if this problem does not cause me a problem like *Force Stop*

The first two lines of program error (Warning):

**Logcat**

```
    01-04 12:20:20.378 2166-2166/com.xxxx.yyyy W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
    01-04 12:20:20.419 2166-2166/com.xxxx.yyyy I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService$JobServiceEngineImpl>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/app/job/JobServiceEngine;
...
```

**AppController.java**

```
    public class AppController extends Application {

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            ActiveAndroid.initialize(this);
        }

    }
...
```

**AndroidManidest.xml**

```
...
    <application
        android:name=".AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@stylexxyyTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon">

        <meta-data
            android:name="AA_DB_NAME"
            android:value="RestClient.db" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="AA_DB_VERSION"
            android:value="1" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="AA_MODELS"
            android:value="com.xxxx.yyyyy.model.DBUserInfo" />
...
```

**DBUserInfo.java**

```
@Table(name = "user_info")
public class DBUserInfo extends Model {

        @Column(name = "user_id", unique = true, onUniqueConflict = Column.ConflictAction.REPLACE)
        public int user_id;
        @Column(name = "name")
        public String name;

        public DBUserInfo() {
            super();
        }

        public DBUserInfo(int user_id, String name) {
            this.user_id = user_id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public static DBUserInfo getRandom() {
            return new Select().from(DBUserInfo.class).executeSingle();
        }


        public static DBUserInfo getUserInfo() {
            return new Select().from(DBUserInfo.class).executeSingle();
        }

        public List<DBUserInfo> getAll() {
            return getMany(DBUserInfo.class, "name");
        }

        public static List<DBUserInfo> getAll() {
            return new Select().from(DBUserInfo.class).orderBy("user_id ASC").execute();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you didn't compile the library properly.can you post the app gradle code?Try to use th eprevious versions of Active Android Library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any code related to your error. Did you share the code where the issue happens? Are you testing on a KitKat or previous device? KitKat and older have issues with Vector Graphics and you have to enable Vector Support as well as handle the vectorSupport tag on src on all images. So I have to assume you have drawable vectors in your project and have put these in the wrong folder or have not properly handled them based on that error, but without more details, that is only a speculation.

Keep in mind folders like no-dpi didn't exist in KitKat days as well as memory issues happen like crazy if not managed very meticulously.

Comment: Sir, can you please tell me how to 'enable Vector Support' ?

Comment: Hi @Psycho there really isn't anything special to do anymore. Just right-click the drawable folder and "new vector asset" then select the SVG graphic from your desktop and Android will reformat it and import it for you. Then you simply use it like a normal drawable, or use Glide library to do it async into views. Unless you are supporting 21 and older, then you would add vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true in your build and app:srcCompat as your image pointer. See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41098015/how-to-set-vectordrawable-as-an-image-for-imageview-programmatically

Comment: @Psycho Hi, take a look here how to enable that: https://chris.banes.dev/appcompat-vector/#enabling-the-flag