# Method setImageResource in onBindViewHolder of RecyclerView Adapter dosent work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

There is an `AppCompatImageView` in my `RecyclerView` that I want to set a vector image to. I have tried a lot of solutions but none of them works (the vector image is not set).
I also checked **this** [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41098015/5528079).

```
class FunctionAdapter(
private val context: FragmentActivity,
private val methods: MutableList<Method>,
private val viewHolderListener1: ViewHolderListener
                                                    ) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<FunctionAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

private val viewHolderListener: ViewHolderListener = viewHolderListener1
private var pos: Int? = null

override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    viewHolder.txtViewMethod.text = methods[position].methodName
    viewHolder.textViewFuncOne.text = methods[position].funcOne
    viewHolder.textViewFuncTwo.text = methods[position].funcTwo
    viewHolder.textViewFuncThree.text = methods[position].funcThree
    viewHolder.textViewFuncFour.text = methods[position].funcFour
    viewHolder.buttonRun.tag = position

    if (methods[position].methodNameFlag == true) {

            val drawableF = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_home)
            viewHolder.checkImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_round_done_all_24px)
            viewHolder.checkImgView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_home))
            viewHolder.checkBox.setImageDrawable(drawableF)
            viewHolder.checkImgView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.ic_round_done_all_24px))
        viewHolder.checkImgView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary))
    } else {
     //            viewHolder.checkImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_black_24dp)

        viewHolder.checkImgView
            .setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.grey_light))
    }}
```

As you see i have tried `setImageResource` and `setImageDrawable` in the `onBindViewHolder` .

#### This is the xml

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/checkBox_test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_done_black_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>
```

Comment: How exactly is it not working?

Comment: what's issue ..?

Comment: @MikeM. it's not changed the image at all.

Comment: Well, if you mean it doesn't change when that "something happens", you'll need to [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] of that something.

Comment: Is it possible that methods[position].methodNameFlag is always false?

Comment: @KeivanEsbati I have debugged it and it wasn't always false

Comment: What's the type of `viewHolder.checkBox`? If it is an `android.widget.CheckBox` then it has not `setImageResource` method.

Comment: what kind of view is checkImgView?

Comment: @roghayehhosseini I added the view but I have mentioned it in the first paragraph of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

above Version 21  you have to follow these steps:

In app's  `build.gradle` you need to include:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}
```

if you wish to below Build Version API 21 you have to add this line in `onCreate()` method.

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I put the `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true); ` in the onCreate() of my fragment and its worked