# Glide placeholder vector drawable resource not found exception

Tags: android, android-glide, android-vectordrawable

Recently I am trying to add `Vector Drawable` in my work. I am using glide to set my drawables. Here is my code :

```
Glide
                .with(mContext)
                .load(resDrawable)
                .placeholder(placeHolderResDrawable)
                .centerCrop()
                .bitmapTransform(new CropCircleTransformation(MyLruBitmapPool.getInstance()))
                .into(imgRoundedView);
```

Here I put `vector drawable` to `resDrawable` and `placeHolderResDrawable`. It was working fine in **`Lolipop`** device. But when I tested it in **`less than lolipop`** than it crashed. When trying to put `drawable` in `placeholder` it gave `Resources$NotFoundException`.

Here is the crash report:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/default_round_profile.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02013d
>                                                                               at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3451)
>                                                                               at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1894)
>                                                                               at com.bumptech.glide.request.GenericRequest.getPlaceholderDrawable(GenericRequest.java:395)
>                                                                               at com.bumptech.glide.request.GenericRequest.begin(GenericRequest.java:265)
>                                                                               at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestTracker.runRequest(RequestTracker.java:36)
>                                                                               at com.bumptech.glide.GenericRequestBuilder.into(GenericRequestBuilder.java:616)
>                                                                               at com.bumptech.glide.GenericRequestBuilder.into(GenericRequestBuilder.java:652)
>                                                                               at com.bumptech.glide.DrawableRequestBuilder.into(DrawableRequestBuilder.java:436)

Comment: post you default_round_profile.xml code

Comment: check if you have placeholder is in v21 folder

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/35898693/6127411

Comment: as i said this is working in lolipop but crashed in bellow lolipop. @ankit i put in default drawable folder

Comment: vector drawable arent support before lollipop

Comment: see this link https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.1m96p0swx

Comment: @ankitagrawal in chrisbanes article it says : "Allows developers to easily use <vector> drawables on all devices running Android 2.1 and above."

Comment: yes but there is step how to enable it and are you using that support library version

Comment: @ankitagrawal yes i did

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112284/discussion-between-ankit-agrawal-and-sayem).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to get the drawable using `ContextCompat` and set it as placeholder:

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, placeHolderResDrawable);
```

So it would be:

```
Glide.with(mContext)
     .load(resDrawable)
     .placeholder(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, placeHolderResDrawable))
     .centerCrop()
     .bitmapTransform(new CropCircleTransformation(MyLruBitmapPool.getInstance()))
     .into(imgRoundedView);
```

**Update for Glide v4:**

```
Glide.with(mContext)
     .load(resDrawable)
     .apply(new RequestOptions()
         .placeholder(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, placeHolderResDrawable))
         .centerCrop()
         .transform(new CropCircleTransformation(MyLruBitmapPool.getInstance())))
     .into(imgRoundedView);
```