# set vector drawable to side drawable in textview in android

Tags: java, android, vector

I have a vector drawable wich I want to set to textview sides Drawable. after some googling some pepole suggesting to put my vector drawable in layerList then set layer list drawable to textview drawables and now my code is:

layerList:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
           <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_sort_up"/>    //vector drawable
</layer-list>
```

get drawable in java:

```
 Drawable ArrowDrawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.selected_arrow);
```

when I run my code on android 6 devices it works fine but when I run it On android 4.4 I got this error message:

```
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/selected_arrow.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0200c1
```

can anybody help about this problem?
**UPDATE**
my problem is not to use vector drawable's in lower than android 5 because I use them right now with appcompatImageviews and works fine my problem is getting vector drawable and set them to textview drawable's in java so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548354/vectordrawable-is-it-available-somehow-for-pre-lollipop-versions-of-android) link do not help me.

Comment: my minSdk version is 15

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26548354/5241933) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for you'r attention but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26548354/5241933) don't help me.
but after some googling I found about vector drawable's that I have to add this line

```
 static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

to my activity and now my app works fine

Comment: medium blog link is broken

Answer (score 0):

> set vector drawable to side drawable in textview in android

**AppCompatTextView** now supports `app:drawableLeftCompat`, `app:drawableTopCompat`, `app:drawableRightCompat`, `app:drawableBottomCompat`, `app:drawableStartCompat` and `app:drawableEndCompat` compound drawables, supporting backported drawable types such as *VectorDrawableCompat*.

Include this in your gradle file

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.1.0-beta01'
```

In your text view you can use

```
app:drawableLeftCompat
app:drawableStartCompat
```

Comment: This is still in beta version... and breaks the recyclerview. Amazing how google didn't fix this yet!