# Android: animated custom views

Tags: java, android, android-layout, animation, android-animation

## EDIT 2: new official training guide

The Developers site released a training guide for UI related stuff, this is the index:

- Animations Overview
- Property Animation Overview
- Animate drawable graphics
- Reveal or hide a view using animation
- Move a View with Animation
- Move views using a fling animation
- Enlarge a view using a zoom animation
- Animate movement using spring physics
- Auto animate layout updates
- Animate layout changes using a transition
- Create a custom transition animation
- Start an activity using an animation

If you are interested in any of these, this is the link:
https://developer.android.com/training/animation/

---

## EDIT: Answers sum up

I found 5 ways to animate in Android:

1. Animate the **properties** of a `View` with [Property Animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) to smoothly change `rotation`, `alpha`, `scale` etc.
2. **Frame Animations** ([AnimationDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html)): change the pictures quickly, so that it looks animated
3. Design the images with **vectors** ([VectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html)) and **animate** them by editing them over time with [AnimatedVectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html).
4. **Override** `onDraw()` on a `View` and perform [Custom Drawing](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html) by painting in the canvas.
5. Use [**Lottie**](http://airbnb.design/lottie/), what reproduces animations from After Effects. Many animations available at [LottieFiles](http://www.lottiefiles.com/).

However, Android provides some **built-in tools** too, such as [**`Scenes`**](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/index.html) (that let you animate the transition among several layouts that share the `Views`), [**`Shared elements`**](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html?hl=en) (that lets you make the ilussion of passing a `View` from one `Activity` to another one) etc.

Many (if not all) of these features were added in **API 21**, click here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548354/vectordrawable-is-it-available-somehow-for-pre-lollipop-versions-of-android/35738726#35738726) for more information.

Here are some interesting articles/blogs on animation:

- A subcategory on a Google made website called [material.io](https://material.io/): [Creative customization](https://material.io/guidelines/motion/creative-customization.html#delightful-details-delightful-details).
- [*How we design a beautiful animation*](http://jeremie-martinez.com/2016/09/15/train-animations/): train animation with animated vectors.
- [*How Android Transitions work*](http://lucasr.org/2014/03/13/how-android-transitions-work/).
- [*Animating to infinity*](http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2014/11/11/animating-to-infinity/): bluetooth animation with vectors
- [*Frame Animations in Android*](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/frame-animations-in-android/): filling up a heart by images rotation.

Last, a couple interesting tools:

- Mac tool to record Android screen on [GitHub](https://github.com/mortenjust/androidtool-mac).
- Video to GIF converter [online](https://ezgif.com/video-to-gif).

---

## Note

I am aware Android provides transformations such as `scale`, `alpha`, `rotate`, `translation` etc.

## Examples

There are 2 examples I would like to look at and compare.

### 1 - Custom View animations

For example, [filling up a glass of water](https://youtu.be/NjjcLbe5pPc?t=1m17s) or [drawing a path](https://youtu.be/K5W9H0ln9Vk?t=1m42s).

### 2 - Complex View animations

For instance, StackExchange App for Android, login screen animation (couldn't find a video on it, also, didn't check if behaves the same in iOS).

## Question

For the first example, I can't think of any other way than playing GIFs, or manually changing images after little time periods.

I do not think this is the case, that's why I would like to ask, **(1)** do you know how it's done?

Regarding the second example, only one idea came to my mind, and that's setting a `Path` and moving the `View` accordingly by passing it somehow after `animate()`. **(2)** Is this possible?

Apart from the mentioned above, **(3)** do you know of other techniques to play animations? (Such as `Scene transitions` - *mentioned in an answer*-)

Please share! Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered animated vector drawables?

Comment: @azizbekian Didn't know about it, but looks super tedious to work with. Looking at the example at [Vector Drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html) guides webpage. I think it's meant for simpler images. Do you think you can achieve the same effect as the images I provided ?

Comment: Theoretically you can. But vector drawables are mainly for icons. If the path in svg is rather simple, that it won't take too much time to render it. [Here](https://medium.com/google-developers/animation-jump-through-861f4f5b3de4#.yckr5zbjf) you can see more details how it can be implemented.

Comment: @azizbekian If you provide an example that is similar to the water glass and answer the question on how to get an animation like the SO App login I would mark it as the best answer.

Comment: Can't understand what animation is at SO App login. On my phone it's the latest version, and it is only splash screen with progress bar.

Comment: @azizbekian You have to log out to see it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Filling up a glass of water" animation is direct canditate of implementing via frame animation, i.e. changing pictures one after the other. [Here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/frame-animations-in-android/) you can see a nice blog post describing how to implement this kind of animation, which basically is the same as "filling up a glass of water" you mentioned:

[image]

The other animation look slightly difficult at first glance.

[image]

But after turning on "Show layout bounds" you can see there is no magic there. Basically this is just a translation animation, which translates a view from one position to another. In case of this animation the difficult part is to implement the algorithm of finding translation coordinates. After that animating is just a couple lines of code via [scene transition animation](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/index.html).

```
// assuming at this step all the views are at the initial position at x0, y0
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootLayout);
// here set view coordinates to x1, y1 - the final position
```

Transitions framework will do the rest for you. It will find the delta and perform animation for you. [Here](http://lucasr.org/2014/03/13/how-android-transitions-work/) you will find a nice article by [Lucas Rocha](https://twitter.com/lucasratmundo?lang=en).

Comment: +1 on this answer, I wrote the more complex "complex view animations" example and it's a bunch of ViewPropertyAnimators starting (semi-random) off screen and ending at translationX(0f) and translationY(0f)

Comment: Fantastic answer. I knew something like [`AnimationDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) existed, but I didn't think it was such a common and widely used technique. The `Scene` transition was also a great contribution, I saw some videos of it, but for some reason I didn't think about it. I think you only missed some info on [`AnimatedVectorDrawables`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html), what was covered by the answer of David Medenjak. Many techniques, great info.

Comment: Before accepting as the best answer, I would like to wait for a couple days more in case someone wants to contribute with something missing. However, no worries, your anwer covers my question. Also, could you share the software used to record the screen and make a GIF out of it?

Comment: Azizbekian, could you answer my previous question?

Comment: @JonZarate, hey! Haven't noticed the question. Sure. There's [a nice tool](https://github.com/mortenjust/androidtool-mac) for easily capturing screen. It captures a video, and then I've converted and resized it to a gif [on the web](https://ezgif.com/video-to-gif).

Answer (score 6):

> do you know of other techniques to play animations?

In Android you have basically 3 ways to implement animations:

- Animate the View (Scale, alpha, rotate, etc) by just using `view.startAnimation(...)`
- Animate the Drawable (Depending on the Drawable, this could be anything from animated vector drawables to [frame animations](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html))
- Doing custom drawing and animation

Obviously just animating a view by framework methods is easier than creating some drawable animation, and creating some drawable (xml) is easier than doing custom drawing.

You mentioned lottie, which just came out a few days ago. We shall see how well it does, but it looks very promising. Under the hood lottie will parse the json and do some custom drawing using `Canvas` and `Path` (3rd bullet point above)
If you can get your hands on After Effects this is probably the "easiest" solution for complex animations (and cross platform!)

People also started sharing animations, you can find them here:
http://www.lottiefiles.com/

---

> do you know how it's done?

The (1) video looks like they do some custom drawing.

- Draw and fill a [`Path`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) for the water, animate the top with some waves while it animates up, and sprinkle with some white spots.
- Draw a the shape of the glass around it

This will involve creating a custom view and/or drawable and overriding `onDraw(Canvas)` `Path.lineTo` as well as some arc, cubic, or quad will do the trick...I'm neither a designer nor a vector specialist :)

I do not think this could easily be achieved by using [animated vector drawables](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html), but you might get it done by applying a path morph animation. (Also animated vector drawables are only supported on 21+ if I am not mistaken)

The (2) Video just animates a Path and wiggles a flag. This can be achieved by using AnimatedVectorDrawables (as e.g. [this blog](http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2014/11/11/animating-to-infinity/) shows) and trimming the path beginnings/ends or again by doing custom drawing (and thus also supporting pre lolipop devices) by animating a Path, e.g. using [`PathMeasure.getSegment()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PathMeasure.html#getSegment(float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Path,%20boolean)) to continuuously animate the path.

The (3) animation, as already pointed out by [azizbekians answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42819790/1837367) is the first mentioned kind, just animating (moving and scaling) views.

---

> Regarding the second example, only one idea came to my mind, and that's setting a Path and moving the View accordingly by passing it somehow after animate(). (2) Is this possible?

Moving views along a path is obviously possible, but then the view would move, and you would still need to find a way to draw the path following it, as explained above.

Comment: Great information, thank you. Regarding the `AnimatedVectorDrawable` minimum API, I think it can be used in API 14 (4.0) with some android support libraies. Check the [link for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35738726/7373404). Already upvoted yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest a library I've written a while ago (published recently), which allows you to create custom views and add animations to them.

You can find it [here](https://github.com/MrMindyMind/AnimatedView-Android) and a very [simple demo here](https://github.com/MrMindyMind/AnimatedView-Demo-Android).
While my demos frankly aren't that impressive, they demonstrate the power of the library and most importantly how to use it.

It works with Android's [TimeInterpolator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/TimeInterpolator.html) and any of its children (as-well as custom ones).

The animations are drawn entirely using Canvas, the only difference here is that you can get an animated value, which changes according to the TimeInterpolator as a function of time.

You can add as many animations as you would like to your View, control them independently of each-other. And on top of that, you are not limited to drawing non-animation things. There's a dedicated method for that (onDrawStatics).

Comment: A new version is currently being developed, based on the same idea, however implemented much better.

Answer (score -2):

For Your Custom view , i suggest you identify the Properties that you want to Animate on .

Let's say a ClockView, You After setting paint,stroke and so on in `OnDraw()`

You might wanna have AsyncMethods/Runnables  which updates the Properties continuously in background , resulting in Frame by frame animation , but it isn't Fraame Animation actually , because you are animating only the properties of view (turn left) and not he tentire frame

There are dozens of examples out there, With little googling you can DIY

Comment: I don't think that's elegant at all

Comment: That's how animations are done buddy, Every thing is just an updation.

Comment: That may be how Android does it, but not how proffesional apps are developed. Not to mention, your `AsyncMethods/Runnables` aproach is an overkill when we already have animations provided by Android. So, in a nutshell, you just suggested to override `onDraw`, and then what? Draw the water glass animation pixel by pixel after 50ms? Do you have an idea of the amoun of work it requires? If you are that sure about it, go on and show an example...